# Designing the sign-up process?

Tags: website-design, forms, registration, signup-signon

I am starting a website consisting of info on local shops, product catalogs, and coupons. now I am in a dilemma over the vendor sign-up process. I want to know which of the following ways should I do it:

1. just ask for contact info, email and get back to them?
2. ask for all details like shop name, type, address, website, contact person name, and then after I verify the details, activate the account and let them fill in the remaining details?

In short what is the best way to get maximum sign ups or how to develop a sign-up which doesn't ask for endless details and reduces abandonment?

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time.  I've removed the second part (about genuine products), but suggest that you ask it as a separate question.

Answer (score 7):

**First** let the vendor create a basic profile by registering their Shop name, email id, and contact info. Then when they signup you can show a bar on the dashboard like LinkedIn's

[image]

or some sort of ticker saying "Please complete you profile for best experience" similar to the one shown in image below. This helps us in notifying the vendor in a very polite manner

[image]

and of course you can send then a periodic mail for the same purpose

Then the vendor can complete their profiles in a multi-step process. In this way, the vendors can fill up their profile as per their convenience. Example of such form could be like this:

[image]

**So, when a user's profile is say 90-100% complete, then you can activate his account for transactions.**

Check out my answer on 
[Single page or multi-page forms?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/36956/single-page-or-multi-page-forms/36964#36964) as it may help you decide.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but doesn't address the question.  Please address the question and give reasoning / justification for your answer.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I went little tangentially with my answer... I've edited the answer...

Comment: Nice !very good suggestions, I am definitely considering them!

Comment: @AnkitSharma Much better answer now :)

Answer (score 3):

Start off by **asking for the least amount of information necessary** to create an account (usually just email address), and then create the account.  Then when they log in for the first time, they are presented with a form with the other necessary information that they need to fill in.

Once someone is committed to a decision, they are far less likely to back away from it. Hence, this strategy results in a significantly **smaller dropoff rate** than asking for all the information upfront.

If you sign up for [Gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/) you will get an example of this style of process.

Comment: how about if I break the sign up process in to 3 steps, in step 1 ask only contact and email id, step 2 ,  address and password, and what they sell and step 3  all other optional info like whether they accepts cards,store timings? , is this a good idea?

Comment: @StanfordSequeira It's better than one long form, but still not as good as what I explained in my answer.